# vs2015 activity log error User:IdeUser, Core attribute 'DateCreated' is not supported.: ArgumentException during GetAttributes at Microsoft.VisualStu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 randomly freezes for me. I've checked the activity log and this is the only error I can find. Is this an error I can fix on my end?

> User:IdeUser, Core attribute 'DateCreated' is not supported.: ArgumentException during GetAttributes at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Profile.ProfileUtility.GetCorrectlyTypedCoreAttribute(String coreAttributeName, Object value) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Profile.ProfileUtility.ExtractCoreAttribute[T](ProfileAttributeBase`1 attribute) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Profile.Client.ProfileHttpClientBase.d__3c.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.IdeUserSession.d__43.MoveNext() (ActivityId: 2f3149d3-4fb7-4ddc-a61a-612d908e9231)
>
> Source: UserConnection

Comment: I have the same issue, not random but on new projects and opening projects. I also get a .NET Runtime error event `System.NotSupportedException` `at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c__DisplayClass2.<ThrowAsync>b__5(System.Object)`. I've tried the steps outlined [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e75a562-2e39-4fda-8c9a-6752ca7f4066/visual-studio-2015-enterprise-crashing?forum=visualstudiogeneral). Do you get any errors showing in your event viewer?

Comment: I did get an error "The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found", but it was about 30 minutes before crashing. Will check again after next crash

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue (seemingly random freezing/crashing) and have the same exception logged.

Comment: SFC and the verification tool issue do not show any issues @GoldfishSandwich. I didn't check the verification tool logs though